# VueJS - access data variables inside loop

Tags: vue.js, scope

I'm having a bit of VueJS nonsense , can you please help?

I declare my variables as such :

```
data () {
  return {
   selectedContacts: [],
   checkedContacts: []
  }
}
```

Then do the following in a method:

```
this.checkedContacts.forEach((checkedContact) => { 
    var found = false
    console.log(this.selectedContacts)
    if (this.selectedContacts) {
      this.selectedContacts.forEach((selectedContact) => {
        if (checkedContact.contactid === selectedContact.contactid) {
          found = true
        }
      })
    }
    if (!found) {
      this.selectedContacts.push(this.checkedContact)
    }
  })
```

I always get the error that selectedContacts is undefined.. how is this possible, it's defined in the data variables. How can I access this variable? i guess it's a scope issue.

Tx

Comment: Can you show how you're defining this _method_? Also, what **exactly** is the full error message and to which line does it refer?

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't for `this.checkedContact`? I don't see that in your `data`

Comment: You're using forEach inside forEach for the same which is the issue.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal what do you mean? For the same _what_?

Comment: Maybe use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of writing your own.

Comment: Indeed, this.checkedContact needs to be checkedContact. The error I get is the following: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at eval (ContactsSelection.vue?8612:126)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VueComponent.addSelectedContacts (ContactsSelection.vue?8612:115)
    at boundFn (vue.esm.js?efeb:190)
    at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2004)
    at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?efeb:1802)

Comment: Array.some gives the same issue .. it's really annoying..

Comment: Ok, I've found the issue, something else was undefining my variable.. sorry for that.